# Why is $p(A) \times p(B|A) = p(B) \times p(A|B)$?

Tags: bayes

Is there an easy way or simple example to get why it must be that

$$
p(A) \times p(B|A) = p(B) \times p(A|B)
$$?

I get that $p(A) \times p(B|A)$ can be seen as probability of $B$ occurring, weighted by the probability of $A$ occurring on which it is being conditioned on.
What's the background for this equation and is it generally valid?

---

Edited Question

Is there an easy way or simple example to get why then it must be that

$$
p(A \cap B) = p(A) p(B|A)
$$?

If I think of $A$ and $B$ as overlapping circles in a Venn-Diagramm, then it seems to me that $B|A$ already would describe the overlap.

Comment: It holds because $A\cap B=B\cap A$. Remember the definition of conditional probability: $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(A)$, if $P(A)>0$.

Comment: Unless you _define_ what exactly _you_ understand by $p(B\mid A)$ and $p(A\mid B)$, the question is difficult to answer. If you mean by $P(B \mid A)$ the ratio $P(B \cap A)/P(A)$ (provided that $P(A) > 0$) as pointed out to you by @Zen, and are willing to allow the interchange of $A$ and $B$ in your definition and accept that $P(A\mid B)$ is, **by definition,**  the ratio $P(A \cap B)/P(B)$ provided that $P(B) > 0$, then Zen's comment that $A\cap B = B \cap A$ contains all that you need to arrive at the result.

Comment: Are you looking for a "philosophical" answer to what we mean by the notation "P(A|B)" ?

Comment: I mean "What's the background for this equation and is it generally valid?" is pretty broad.

Comment: I guess my problem is with the definition. Where does it come from? But that's usually the point with definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer in words:  they're both equal to the probability of (A and B) occurring.

(Probability of A) times (Probability of B, given that A has happened) equals (Probability that both A and B happen).

Similarly, (Probability of B) times (Probability of A, given that B has happened) equals (Probability that both A and B happen).

Comment: That's also a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 7):

First, recall

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$$

and consequently

$$P(A∩B)=P(A|B)P(B)$$

The trick here is to realize the very simple fact that $P(A∩B)= P(B∩A)$. This fact is quite intuitive; the probability that UNC wins and Duke loses is the same as the probability that Duke loses and UNC wins. So, in reality, we have two options:

$$P(A∩B)=P(A|B)P(B)$$

and

$$P(B∩A)=P(B|A)P(A)$$

and so

$$P(B|A)P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)$$

Comment: Why is is that so many statisticians (or maybe just wannabe statisticians in view of the soubriquet TrynnaDoStat) insist that _Bayes'_ rule states that $$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}?$$ Isn't this just the _definition_ of the conditional probability of $A$ given that $B$ occurred (provided that $P(B) > 0$? Bayes' _formula_ or Bayes' _theorem_  deals with what the Reverend called _inverse_ probability: it tells you what $P(B\mid A)$ is in terms of $P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: I don't want to get into a discussion about names, it could be called Chicken Dance Theorem for all I care, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat You're actually taking my problem from the end. To clarify, my question is much rather, how come that $p(A | B) p(B) = p(A \cap B)$? Rearranging this to whatever other form is not the problem. But I think I understand better now that I have the hint about the combination of A and B.

Comment: I see, so your question is more asking for an intuitive explanation of why $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A∩B)$? Do you want a proof or an intuitive explanation?

Comment: @TrynnadDoStat Have you even **bothered** to read the link that you have referred me to? It **does not** say that Bayes's rule or Bayes' theorem (or the Chicken Dance Theorem if you will) is what **you** claim it is. -1 pending an edit of your answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Seriously, can we leave it just there? "@ TrynnaDoStat" Exactly. But I think I get that from looking at a Venn Diagram.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I understand your point now and will take out "Bayes Theorem" from my answer.

Comment: @TMOTTM Do you mind editing your question? Based on the discussion in these comments it seems to me that the question you are really asking is for an intuitive explanation for why $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A∩B)$ which is different from the question you asked.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat OK, I reversed my downvote, but you really should take out another reference to Bayes' theorem too. You are correct in asking TMOTTM to revise his question.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat You're right. BUt I only realize this now that I was reminded of this relationship.

Answer (score 7):

If $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A), P(B) > 0$, how can I compute the probability that *both* events occurred? That is, how can I determine $P(A\cap B)$?
Well, if $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events, then I know that
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)\tag{1}$$
(that is just the *definition* of independence) and so $P(A\cap B)$ is straightforward
to compute.  Wouldn't it be wonderful if I could write $P(A\cap B)$ *in general*
as $P(A)\alpha(B;A)$ where $\alpha(B;A)$ is some quantity
(obviously dependent on $A$ and $B$) with the magical property that
that $P(A)\alpha(B;A)$ has value $P(A \cap B)$? Now for all this to
happen, we must have that $\alpha(B;A) = P(B)$ when
$A$ and $B$ are independent (so that $(1)$ holds). We can say a bit
more about this magical function.  Since $(A\cap B) \subset A$, and so
$P(A\cap B) \leq P(A)$,
$\alpha(B;A)$ has maximum value $1$, and since it is possible that
$P(A\cap B) = 0$, $\alpha(B;A)$ can be as small as $0$. So, since
$\alpha(B;A)$ always has value in $[0,1]$, that is, it looks like a
probability and quacks (acts?) like a probability, we could even call it
a *probability* if we like, except we have not really said
 *what* $\alpha(B;A)$ is the probability *of*.  But whatever this
thingy is or what it means, we always have that
$$\begin{align}
P(A\cap B) &= P(A)\alpha(B;A) \tag{2}\\
\alpha(B;A) &= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Similarly, if we interchange the roles of $A$ and $B$ in the above,
we can write
$$\begin{align}
P(B\cap A) &= P(B)\alpha(A;B) \tag{4}\\
\alpha(A;B) &= \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(B)}\tag{5}
\end{align}$$
and since $A\cap B = B \cap A$, we can use $(2)$ and $(4)$ to 
deduce that
$$P(A)\alpha(B;A) = P(B)\alpha(A;B)\tag{6}$$
which looks  *almost the same* as what the OP is asking about.

So, what *are* these quantities $\alpha(B;A)$ and $\alpha(A;B)$ that 
are "defined" by $(3)$ and $(5)$?  Well, *one* way to think about this
is to consider that in order for both $A$ and $B$ to have occurred, 
obviously $A$ must have occurred (which has probability $P(A)$), and
*given* that we have already assumed that $A$ has occurred, we should
think of $\alpha(B;A)$ as the *conditional* probability of $B$ given
that we have already assumed that $A$ has occurred. Thus, we call
$\alpha(B;A)$ as the

> conditional probability of $B$ given that $A$ has occurred, denoted 
>   $P(B\mid A)$ and *defined* as
>   $$ P(B\mid A) 
> = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} ~ \text{provided that} ~ P(A) > 0.\tag{7}$$

Notice that when $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$,
that is, knowing that $A$ has occurred does not in the least change
your estimate of the probability of $B$.

All of which is fine and dandy, but what is the *intuition* behind
all this? Well, many people make sense of probabilities as long-term
*relative frequencies* and so let us consider a sequence of $N$ trials
of the experiment, $N$ large. If the event $A$ occurred $N_A$ times on
these $N$ trials and the event $B$ occurred on $N_B$ trials, then
$$P(A) \approx \frac{N_A}{N}, \quad P(B) \approx \frac{N_B}{N}.$$
Similarly, $$P(A\cap B) \approx \frac{N_{A\cap B}}{N}$$ where we
note that the trials on which $A\cap B$ occurred are necessarily
a *subset* of the $N_A$ trials on which $A$ occurred (as well as a
subset of the $N_B$ trials on which $B$ occurred).
But, $P(B\mid A)$ is the (conditional) probability of $B$ given that
event $A$ has occurred, and so let us consider the $N_A$ trials on
which $A$ has occurred.  **On this subsequence** of $N_A$ trials, what is
the *relative frequency* of $B$? Well, $B$ occurred on exactly $N_{A\cap B}$
of these $N_A$ trials, and so
$$P(B\mid A) \approx \frac{N_{A\cap B}}{N_A}
= \frac{\frac{N_{A\cap B}}{N}}{\frac{N_{A}}{N}}\approx \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$
which matches the definition in $(7)$.

---

OK, so now let the down-voting begin....

Answer (score 3):

Just trying a graphical intuition... Hope it flies...[image]

Answer (score 2):

$p(B\mid A)p(A) = p(B\cap A)=p(A\mid B)p(B)$

Comment: Can you expand this a little? I'm not sure this will clarify the issue sufficiently for the OP.

Comment: +1 I like this because it goes to the point and responds to the request for "easy way or simple example."

Comment: Just to be sure, the comma in the notation $p(A, B)$ is another way of writing $\cap$?

Comment: @TMOTTM Yes, the comma and the cap both mean (A and B).

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is like this. Suppose we have A containing two events, "A = 1" or "A = 2", and B containing three events, "B = 1", "B = 2", or "B = 3". The (arbitrary) cell counts for the occurrence of the events are listed in the following table.

[image]

Now we can do a simple example:
\begin{align*}
P(A=1) & = \frac{6}{21} \\
P(B=2) &= \frac{7}{21} \\
P(A=1 \mid B=2) &= \frac{2}{7} \\
P(B=2 \mid A=1) &= \frac{2}{6} \\
\end{align*}
which yields to
\begin{align*}
P(A=1) \times P(B=2 \mid A=1) &= \frac{6}{21} \times \frac{2}{6} = \frac{2}{21} \\
P(B=2) \times P(A=1 \mid B=2) &= \frac{7}{21} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{2}{21}
\end{align*}

It's easy to verify that the equation does hold for other occurrence of event A and B.

The equation is generally valid. That's no magic of course.

If A and B are independent, then $P(B|A) = P(B)$, $P(A|B) = P(A)$. The two sides of the equation reduce to $P(A)P(B)$. The equation holds.

If A and B are not independent, then it's easy to be proved by the definition of conditional probability (or Bayes' theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Let us motivate the formula for conditional probability. We keep things are simple as possible. $S$, our sample space, will be finite. Let $E$ and $F$ be subsets of it (*events*).

When we write, $P(E|F)$ we are saying, "probability of $E$ given $F$". Thus, instead of the possibilities being in $S$, they are now all in $F$ since we are told that event $F$ has occurred. The new sample space is $F$. To find the probability of $E$ given $F$, it remains to count the number of possibilities which are in $E$. It would be wrong to write $|E|$ since this is counting the possibilities outside of $F$ (the new sample space). Therefore, there are $|E\cap F|$ possibilities of $E$ which happen within $F$.

It follows by the finite probability formula (event size divided by sample size), 
$$ P(E|F) = \frac{|E\cap F|}{|F|} $$

But let us rewrite this formula to have probabilities on the right side. We use, 
$$ P(E|F) = \frac{|E\cap F|}{|S|} \cdot \frac{|S|}{|F|} = \left( \frac{|E\cap F|}{|S|} \right) \bigg/\left( \frac{|F|}{|S|} \right) = \frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)} $$